# Send File via Bluetooth even other device not in range android application

Tags: android, bluetooth

Image explanation

[image]

From above image, Let's say I want to send files to device C from device A, But they are not in Range. On the other hand, Device A & B and B & C are in range. So, is there have any way I can send any file to device C by some assisting of device B. I read about piconet, But really confused is it really possible. Note Please this is not my assignment, it is my personal project.

[is it possible implementation this way any protocol available]